# I get an Error when I try to round a gpiozero variable

Tags: python, gpiozero

I want to round a variable, but when I run my code it returns the following
Error: "TypeError: type DiskUsage doesn't define __ round __ method". I already looked up in the internet but I didn't found something which can solve my problem.
Here is my code:

```
from gpiozero import DiskUsage

disk = DiskUsage()
disk = round(DiskUsage(),3)
print('Current disk usage: {}%'.format(disk))
```

I want to round it because the value DiskUsage() returns is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:
First I have to do:
`disk = DiskUsage()`
and then:
`disk = disk.usage`
and now I'm able to round the variable by using `disk = round(disk,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you already set "disk = DiskUsage()". Try this:

```
from gpiozero import DiskUsage

disk = round(DiskUsage(),3)
print('Current disk usage: {}%'.format(disk))
```

Comment: Thank you but I doesn't work. It returns the same error again

Comment: Does DiskUsage() return a string? If that's the case you need to cast it into an int, like this: 

disk = round(int(DiskUsage()),3)

Comment: I solved it. I have to do `disk = DiskUsage()` and  `disk = disk.usage` and now I'm able to round it : `disk = round(disk,3)`. But thank you the idea to look what typ DiskUsage() is was great. Thank you!@Kremklatt